# Series Not Working in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

So I am creating a highcharts bar chart in a function inside my jQuery script, and it was working fine until I tried to incorporate different colors for each bar of the bar chart. My code is basically as follows

```
function BarChart(title, gType, list, numbers){
    var data = [];
    var allData = [];
    var series = [];
    var len = numbers.length;
    var colors = ['#7cb5ec', '#434348', '#90ed7d', '#f7a35c', '#8085e9', '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#8085e8', '#8d4653', '#91e8e1'];
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        data.push({
            y: numbers[i],
            color:colors[i]
        });
        allData.push(data[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        series.push({
            name: list[i],
            data: allData[i]
        });
    }
```

Then I go on and create the chart and for series, I simply put

```
series: series
```

But no bars come up, only the legend, the title, the yAxis title and the xAxis title. If you can help me out that be great, hopefully my question is clear enough! Thanks!

P.S.

when I just put

```
series:[{
data: data
}]
```

it works, but then all the legend says is Series 1 and I don't want that, I want it to actually show the name of each data with its corresponding color, thanks again!

Comment: what does the output of the series variable look like once you're done looping? I have to assume that is where your issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you were still looking into the "Series 1" problem in the legend. I found an interesting way to have each point be it's own series and still group correctly on the x-axis. It works by abusing bar stacking:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal'
  }
},
```

and setting an increment x value on each data point:

```
data.forEach(function(val, i) {
    seriesData.push({
      name: categories[i],
      color: colors[(i % colors.length)],
      data: [{
        x: i,
        y: val
      }]
    });
  });
```

Here is a working fiddle built from an example I derived from the highcharts docs:

http://jsfiddle.net/89efeqhs/

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem, but just for reference to anyone else who runs into this problem, its rater simple. Write this code,

```
plotOptions:{
series:{
    colorByPoint: true
}}
```

And highcharts will color each bar/column/line individually.

For reference here is the highcharts page that showed me this:http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar